# Can I put an electrical panel in a closet in a closet?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, inspection, clearance

That's not a typo in the subject line.

I am finishing part of my basement to put in a new master bedroom, bathroom, and closet. I was planning on putting the panel in the walk-in closet but enclosing it in a full enclosure of the appropriate size (floor to ceiling, 30" wide, 36" deep), but the inspector said that is not allowable because the panel would be in a closet in a closet and since the outer closet is a clothes closet, the panel is still in the "vicinity" of ignitable materials. I don't quite understand this since there will be a solid layer of finished wall between the panel and any ignitable materials. Thoughts?

I then came up with a second idea to still create a "subcloset"; however, this time, it would have a small door leading directly to the bedroom. The panel would still have the appropriate clearance, but to get to that clearance, the "hallway" (about 3' long) would only be about 18" wide. Without me providing exact dimensions of the door, the inspector approved this idea via email but said the door to the panel must be at least 24" wide. Is this correct? Would this separate closet need a door of at least 24"?

Thanks!

Comment: I think if the inspector said the door must be 24" wide, it means that he's not going to sign it off if it isn't.

Comment: Got to be big enough for an electrician to get thru.

Comment: Measure your width shoulder to shoulder. You need to be able to access the panel with two hands. I can imagine an allowance for a 3in or 6in deep cubby that's 18in wide, but not a 3ft corridor.

Comment: Unless the panel is already mounted & wired up, I'd recommend moving your panel location. Sounds like that would be _much_ easier and make more sense than wasting the floor space to make the "hallway".

Comment: @FreeMan unfortunately, this is a not a new build house. We are just remodeling half of the basement to create a nicer/larger master bedroom. Otherwise, I totally agree.

Comment: @P2000 sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The panel will still have the appropriate 30" x 36" clearance around the panel. It's just the "hallway" leading to that enclosure is apparently supposed to be 24" instead of 18". The reason I'm stuck on the 18" is because it makes the required fix only a moderate pain instead of a large pain. The 24" requirement is apparently not in the code but is instead the city standard.

Comment: Yes, that 24in makes sense, it's a *building* code, because people in general (of various sizes), including fire fighters with full gear need to get to it

Comment: @Cody -- the 24" is probably for egress/ingress reasons

Answer (score 2):

Electrical panels are something that you have to design around for a basement.   Would you have the main stack running through the middle of your bedroom... No.

Why?   Because it is common sense.

It is also common sense to not have an electrical panel in a closet for various reasons.   So if you are going to build a room for your panel inside the closet you still have to abide by all of the normal restrictions.   If he said 24" door that's what you have to do.   I for one would change the design.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. I do understand why it is against code to have a panel in a clothes closet, but I figured if we built an enclosure around the panel (even with fire resistant drywall), that would suffice. I don't quite understand why that wouldn't. How is that different than changing the design so that a small hallway (24" wide, 3' long) leads directly between the panel and the bedroom? There is still the same barrier (framed wall with drywall) in between the panel and the clothes, but the door is just in a different location.

Comment: why something is in the code is moot.   The inspector and therefor you need to follow it.   You can probably build a hallway for it, if approved by city.   That sounds really goofy though

Comment: The inspector approved the hallway idea but not the enclosure within the closet idea. Basically, it seems he is hooked up on the placement of the door. The hallway idea means the panel can be directly accessed from the bedroom, whereas the enclosure idea means the panel is in a closet, even though it's completely closed in and no longer a hazard to nearby clothes.

Comment: it sounds like inspector doesn't want to be on the hook if something happens.   Yes you can argue about the "same" safety.   But the letter of the code says don't do this, and you are doing, albeit in a way that should be just as safe.   I can tell you though your insurance company won't care how safe you thought it was... they will use the code variance as an excuse to deny coverage.   Then you will sue the city for OKing something that didn't meet code to recover the loss of your home.

Comment: There are lots of things that you have to do that really don't make sense to meet codes.   As a homeowner you haven't had to see what someone like me has had to do - in many cases make a situation WORSE to meet code.   I have been down the panel inspector road many many times.   It is a discussion that quite frankly scares me - because some panels have to be grandfathered in (had one 3 inches from a wall).   I even clean up around panels in storage rooms before inspections!   Talk to your inspector and make an ally, see if he can help you with design.   Your best option.

Comment: @DMoore -- this really boils down to "can you access an electrical room (closet) via a walk-in closet?"

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Not really.   I just went through this exact scenario last year.    I had basement reno.   The was going to bump an existing closet that was 3x8 to a 12x8 mega closet.   The panel was right next to the existing and would be in the middle of now a closet as big as a bedroom...  No chance with the town because I was putting up shelves and classifying as a closet.   I guess I could have lied and called it another bedroom (shotgun).    The whole firecrew in town could have held a meeting in the closet and still it was a no.

Comment: @DMoore in that "mega closet" do you think you could have framed/drywalled a 3' x 2'6" enclosure around the panel and then been cleared? Or because it's still technically in a closet would it still have been a no?

Comment: @Cody - I don't ask to do things like that.   I have learned when you try to work around the rules one of two things happens.   You don't meet some tiny criteria and you spent a lot of money on nothing or the inspector starts going over everything with a fine tooth comb... its just not worth it.    The question isn't what could I have done.    It is what will your inspector let you do.   Some town inspectors will just tell you, don't label it as a closet to let it slide... yours didn't (mine didn't).

Answer (score 0):

Everything the inspector told you is correct and consistent with the national electrical code. The door must be so wide to allow an electrician unencumbered egress in an emergency. Also to provide sufficient working space.